# Why couldn't Harry or anybody else see Peter Pettigrew aka Scabbers on the Marauder's Map when Lupin could?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, marauders-map

Fred and George stumbled upon the Marauder's map in their first year. They passed it on to Harry while in their fifth year. Also note that, while talking to Harry on the train, Ron described Scabbers as being "Percy's old rat".

Hence, we can safely assume that the twins had the Marauder's Map for about five years. How could they not see Peter Pettigrew on the map, with Percy for first two years and with Ron for the next three years?

How come Harry didn't see Peter? How was Lupin the only one able to see Peter on the map?

Comment: Interesting question, think it's something that was allowed just for the sake of the story, but he shouldve showed up on the map earlier. Extra questions this one brings to my mind: 1. was Percy's rat always Peter, or was there a rat called scabbers before and did Peter take his place along the way. 2. If Peter was Percy's rat, and he was undercover for all these years. Why would he be Percy's rat to begin with? Before Harry's friendship with Ron the Weasleys were of no significant value for Death Eaters. Good thing you asked this question, I always felt this part of the story needed digging.

Comment: @HansWassink Sirius has a theory with respect to this. Remember he tells Harry, Ron and Hermione that Pettigrew just wanted to find a wizards family to keep up with news with the magical world, and that he was so "lucky" that he ended up with a family that would eventually include Harry Potter's best pal at school.

Comment: @HansWassink You're welcome. Oh, and one more thing: the Weasleys were always important to the Death Eaters, since they were in the Order (Arthur, Molly and Bill).

Comment: How do you know Lupin was the only one ABLE to see Peter? What if he was the only one to NOTICE peter?

Comment: @Janoma The Weasleys only joined the Order after Pettigrew had been exposed and Voldemort had returned.  The Weasleys were a poor, if respectable, pure blood family with very little influence in the scheme of things.  They weren't particularly worth watching, but they provided Wormtail a place from which he could observe wizarding society.

Comment: Didn't scabbers sleep in Ron's bed every night? That would have looked odd on the map... maybe the brothers didn't want to get into an awkward situation.

Comment: I'm confused by the last line of the question. I thought Harry actually noticed Peter Pettigrew. This may be recollecting the movie version of events, but I'm pretty certain Harry comments on the map being "broken" to Lupin because it shows someone he knows to be dead. This triggers Lupin to re-think his positions concerning Peter and Sirius, which eventually leads him to the correct conclusion.

Comment: @Ellesedil I'm pretty sure actually that that's in the film only... Harry isn't searching the castle grounds in the book: he was caught just after his cloak slipped off his face whilst he was throwing (was it?) dirt etc. at Draco and his cronies. He rushed back and Ron tried to cover for him but Severus made him pull out his pockets and read it - pretty sure near the witch statue that was the secret passage.

Answer (score 93):

Rowling was asked this question about Fred and George:

http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=65

> *Why didn't Fred and George notice Peter Pettigrew on the Marauder's Map before ("Prisoner of Azkaban")?*
>
> It would not have mattered if they had. Unless somebody was very familiar with the story of Sirius Black (and after all, Sirius was not Mr. and Mrs. Weasley's best friend – indeed, they never knew him until after he escaped from Azkaban), Fred and George would be unlikely to know or remember that Peter Pettigrew was the person Sirius had (supposedly) murdered. Even if Fred and George HAD heard the story at some point, why would they assume that the 'Peter Pettigrew' they occasionally saw moving around the map was, in fact, the man murdered years before?
>
> Fred and George used the map for their own mischief-making, so they concentrated, naturally enough, on those portions of the map where they were planning their next misdeeds. And finally, you must not forget that hundreds of little dots are moving around this map at any given time… Fred and George did not know everyone in school by name, so a single unfamiliar name was unlikely to stand out.

Comment: I realize that she gets to make the rules, but this is a pretty poor explanation, honestly.  Surely at some point Fred and George would have looked around Gryffindor tower and seen Peter Pettigrew, a boy who didn't belong, just a floor above or below them in the middle of the night (depending on when they looked.)

Comment: @JasonPatterson: True that. I'd go so far as to say that Peter Pettigrew spent a lot of the time on the map right next to Ronald Weasly. Stupid explanation. At least the movie tried to correct it by showing Harry noticing him.

Comment: https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/photo.goodreads.com/hostedimages/1379786089i/478662.jpg

Comment: @JasonPatterson: The omission of such a realization in the books should prove that they didn't have such a realization. Similarly, the books are written from Harry's perspective. _New_ things are talked about, but things that to Harry are everyday (from things as trivial as doorknobs on doors, to less trivial things like flying candles) are omitted as Harry no longer has to think twice about them. Not everything gets mentioned every time, especially not when irrelevant to the plot.

Comment: @JasonPatterson Why would they be looking at the Gryffindor dorm? The twins only used the map to plan their wild hijinks, which I imagine mainly involved sneaking into places they weren't allowed, or access secret areas (none of which were in the dormitory). Presumably the novelty of just watching people move about was long exhausted after their first year.

Comment: @Flater That's true, we don't see everything.  However, if you were going to be making trouble in the night and happened to see a strange name in your brother's bed, you don't think they'd investigate?  It seems like a pretty big deal to me, and I can't see Fred or George ignoring it.  I'm not sure what is trivial about that information.

Comment: @DavidS For the same reasons Harry does.  First, when he sneaks out in the night, he has to make sure that the coast is clear, including the tower.  Second, we see Harry being nosy and watching people for several years, surely Fred and George at least could have done the same.  Third, we have no idea what F & G used the map for in addition to the things you mention.

Comment: @JasonPatterson: _"you don't think they'd investigate?"_ Your question relies on the fact **that** they noticed it. My argument is that they didn't notice it; evidenced by the fact that they never raise the topic, and that it seems logical to raise the topic _if you notice it_. If shooting someone in the head kills them, and this person is alive, then it stands to reason that he has not been shot in the head (yet).

Comment: @Flater Peter Pettigrew was in Ron's possession at Hogwarts for most of three years, during which time the Weasley brothers had and used the map but never noticed a stranger in their tower.  The statement that you objected to simply said that JKR's reason why was a poor explanation, not that it was impossible.  My reply was pointing out that it was clear that they (Weasleys or Potter) did not see Pettigrew in the tower, because that would have been nontrivial.  I think we're agreeing on that point...

Comment: @DavidS I don't know about you, but whenever I use a map to navigate I always locate my starting point as well as my ending point, so that I can trace out a route between them. That's why I've never been satisfied with Rowling's answer--to me, Fred and George ought to have glanced at Gryffindor Tower nearly every time they used the Map.

Plus, Scabbers _was_ present in their first year, as the rat belonged to Percy at the time.

Comment: @BolteAltamont: To be fair though, this isn't a map that tells you where you need to go. F&G aren't looking for directions, so there's less reason to look at your starting point. There's a good argument to be made that they used the map to safely enter places they weren't allowed to be; which would then not apply to their own private quarters as they are allowed to be there.

Comment: @BoltAltamont What Flater said. i've just realised I always assumed that each Gryffindor years dormitory was on a different level of the castle (so Fred and George would never see Harrys dorm unless looking) but then I realised I don't know how the map handles floors. Indeed, without knowing more about the map it's hard to answer - for example, if it's like a normal map then Gryffindor tower would be drawn very small, with upwards of thirty overlapping names in a small area - you'd have to be looking for a specific name to have a hope of making one out. Hmm.

Comment: Right, so they never realised there was some Peter sleeping with their elder brother. Or they did not care. Weird.

Comment: @DavidS I concede Flater's point. Still, we know the Gryffindor dormitories are visible because Harry sees Ginny sleeping there in Deathly Hallows. Perhaps you do have to be looking for someone individually, but there are floors everywhere in Hogwarts, so the Map must have some better way of handling them other than just having the names overlap. And why wouldn't they be looking out for Percy? If you're sneaking out of the common room, you check for anyone who might stop you. Snape in his office? Filch out of the way? Percy asleep? It seems only natural.

Comment: like The Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon ?

Comment: Translation: "I screwed up, but here's some baloney explanation so I don't have to actually admit it."

Comment: @BrandonL Your translation: I don't like that the twins didn't notice someone they wouldn't have even thought a second about (assuming they were even interested in looking where Ron was which is highly unlikely) so I'll just call it a bilge explanation of Rowling's because she's too afraid to admit she's made a mistake... Only she has done exactly that. This isn't one of the cases because it's not a mistake. I mean I'm a cynic but I find it rather odd that so many people here seemingly find these little things so annoying that it must be a plot-hole, must be a mistake..

Comment: @BrandonL ...and personally I think what a terrible thing. People are actually that bothered by something that shouldn't matter (and the majority of the readers it probably doesn't bother and this site is most certainly not a large enough sample size wrt how many have read the book to say so) they call it out, complain about it etc. instead of enjoying the book. Besides nothing is perfect but here's a thought for you: **Maybe she doesn't see it as an issue and so didn't even care about it?** You know it might not be about a mistake...

Comment: @Browsing.  Would Fred and George know every name of hundreds of people at Hogwarts? This question  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171615/how-many-students-attended-hogwarts   says the official number of Hogwarts students is 1000 and that fan estimates range from 280 to 700-1400.  People vary greatly in how sociable they are.  So are Fred and George sociable enough to know every one of 280 to 1400 people well enough to notice a new name?

Comment: @JamesPatterson the twins didn't know who created the map, how it came to exist or the exact magic behind it. Even if they see the name peter pettigrew I doubt they will think twice about it. If they saw the name peter pettigrew on Ron's bed or by Ron and they didn't see anything because the rat is in Ron's pocket, they will just assume the map is faulty. They are just kids who want to have fun.

Comment: @BernardtheBear there's no james patterson here :P try reading alex cross

Comment: @BernardtheBear why would they assume the map is faulty? do you have any younger siblings? if i had this kind of map, then i would check up on my younger siblings all the time. in general, i would check up on my friends and family. not necessarily specifics, but surely the recurring 'peter pettigrew' would stand out. you think fred and george never checked up on ron or ginny?

Comment: @JasonPatterson i think it's worse than that. they wouldn't look around gryffindor tower, but they'd surely check up on friends and family. or maybe not really check up but they may be looking at the map for fun and then 'ron weasley' may catch their eyes subconsciously and then they'll incidentally notice the name 'peter pettigrew'. maybe once or twice the name wouldn't really register in their conscious mind. but i believe at least 3x it would register. i believe mentalists like keith barry or derren brown would back us up.

Answer (score 56):

This is purely conjecture, but it's entirely possible that the Marauders placed some extra protection on the Map in case it were to fall into the wrong hands -- a "hide-the-Marauders" function, if you will. If you think about it, this makes sense -- for, as we know, it *did* fall into the wrong hands, and they wouldn't want anyone to know about their monthly excursions or any of their other Invisibility Cloak adventures. Moreover, they probably only would have wanted it to be a temporary function, so that they might be able to find each other if necessary.

So let's say that there was this hide-the-Marauders function, and it was enabled when Filch confiscated it. Fast forward to Fred and George discovering it. They don't notice anything wrong with it, of course, because none of the Marauders are supposed to be at Hogwarts...until the year in which Lupin arrives. Still, it's clear they don't use the Map much anymore by this point -- they've outgrown it, and they're even passing it on to Harry. Nobody notices that the new Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher is never on the Map -- and why would they? Both Harry and the Weasley twins probably like Lupin, so he's not somebody they'd be watching out for; plus, it's probably a lot harder to notice someone's *absence* from the Map than someone's presence on it (especially, regarding the case in point, if that someone shares a common room with you).

Then Lupin confiscates the Map, and what does he do with it? He's smart -- he uses it to watch out for Harry, as we know he did on the day of Buckbeak's execution; he must also want to use it to watch out for Sirius Black, who has already managed to break into Hogwarts once. So he disables the hide-the-Marauders function, but by now Pettigrew (as Scabbers) is hiding out at Hagrid's out of fear, and no longer living in the Gryffindor Common Room. Because Lupin isn't focusing on Hagrid's hut -- why would he? -- he doesn't notice his old school friend until one night, when Harry, Ron, and Hermione sneak out to see Hagrid...

Again, based purely on conjecture and circumstantial evidence, but that's how I've always justified it in my mind.

Comment: I love this theory, as you say, conjecture, but the reality is that there are some ticky-tacky issues in any series, I read an interview with George RR Martin where he expresses great concern for the mental well-being of the folks who send him letters about similar tiny issues that Martin himself stated he was not aware of in his books. That said, you've come up with a very creative answer that would fit well in the storyline, well played.

Comment: This is the only theory that actually could work.  Of course the Marauders must have also put in a "Hide the Dark Lord" function -- as the twins never spotted Voldemort/Riddle riding around on Quirrell. ;)

Comment: @BrockAdams Or they simply had no interest in tailing teachers..? I mean she points out that it was for mischief making. Okay yes they enchant snowballs to hit Quirrell ironically in the back of the head (iirc) but they hardly needed the map for that.

Comment: @the_SJC Well said on that (I get the impression you agree with said George). I would say it's not mental well-being in the sense of illness so much as it's so ridiculous to be concerned about these things **that are only a problem because they imagine them to be**. The tragedy is they don't enjoy the story as much and that's just a waste....it's their loss however.

Comment: @Pryftan, when you are breaking school rules, like the Marauders (and Weasley twins), you pay extra super special attention to where the teachers are and what they're doing.  The whole point is not to get caught by said teachers.

Comment: @BrockAdams And they didn’t need the map for that. And they had their own methods didn’t they? Yes or how else do you think they got the map in the first place? So my point remains. But not getting caught is irrelevant to my point anyway.

Comment: This theory wouldn't even need Lupin to disable the hide-the-Marauders function. It'd be perfectly plausible for the map to hide Marauders from **everyone except other Marauders**. (Does anyone except Lupin ever see the Peter Pettigrew dot on the map in PoA?)

Comment: Excellent explanation, even if its conjecture. Especially the point of 'hide the marauders function'. Sounds like something Marauders would absolutely do to protect themselves.

Comment: +1. My guess is that there isn't a "hide-the-Marauders" function per se, but that the map knows to show the Marauders only when a Marauders opens it.

Comment: @BrockAdams: I'd argue that Voldemort/Riddle would never show up on the Marauders map inside Quirrel - he's attached to the other side of Quirrel's head at that time, and it's not like Harry Potter notices Voldemort also continuously just slightly ahead of his eye sockets on the map.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Which is to say, it seems likely that the Marauders Map likely requires more than a part of the soul to be tracked - it would also explain why Riddle isn't revealed as continuously tailing Ginny, nor was Voldemort showing up just in the unplottable part of the map where the Diadem was holding part of his soul the whole time. Even the original Marauders might've been confused by that since it was likely there before them. Or maybe that's why the Room of Requirement isn't on the Maurauder's Map - "This room of the map must be defective - Voldemort *clearly* isn't here.".

Answer (score 28):

I always thought that Fred and George (and later, Harry), never used the map while Percy (and later, Ron) was holding Scabbers, which probably happened only during bedtime. At any other time, the name of Peter Pettigrew (for example, at the Great Hall), would have been insignificant to those who didn't know him.

Also, remember that the map showed "hundreds of tiny dots with labels", so, for all Fred, George and Harry knew, Pettigrew could have been just another regular student they didn't know, and who happened to be nearby. This is not shown properly in the movies, where the dots and labels in the maps are larger than what's described in the books (for obvious reasons, though).

Comment: Considering how everyone knew who Sirius Black was, I doubt that a wizard family like the Weasleys wouldn't know who Peter Pettigrew is..

Comment: Maybe Percy, Charlie and Bill, but not the twins, who were younger. Anyway, it seems like Arthur and Molly don't let their kids know too much, especially stuff that is "too dark".

Comment: Real life analogy: I could name a handful of serial killers, but couldn't tell you any of his victims' names.  I bet most people are similar.

Comment: Also, most people would remember that Sirius was convicted for murdering 13 muggles, since they associated this with his alleged support of Voldemort. The death of a wizard could have been considered secondary and forgotten by the masses.

Comment: 12 muggles, sorry.

Comment: @Janoma Yes..because most children there would have been old enough to remember let alone know all the details; hell, the wizarding world didn't know all the details did they? Ridiculous. Ah..wait, I read that wrong. You're saying that they wouldn't have really thought much of Peter but they would of Sirius. Though my point on that it probably wouldn't register in their mind is valid. Definitely agree with you.

Comment: @BrendanLong I don't think so. Even so they were too young to know much on it and they were far too occupied thinking of their own mischief-making. Ask yourself this too: where was the map until the twins took it in their first year? It's not like the older children had access to it and they probably didn't even know it existed. Did they even know the full story? Doubtful seeing as there wasn't even a trial and definitely not in the sense that they had it all wrong as for Secret Keeper etc.

Answer (score 18):

I think that the answer to this question would be that Fred and George's knowledge of the castle was so complete that they were only using the map intermittently, and only to find out where Filch and the teachers were.

As such, they were unlikely to look in Gryffindor Tower, where Scabbers was most of the time.

---

The events that took place when Harry was handed the Marauder's map went like:

1. Fred and George gave Harry the map;
2. When Scabbers disappeared and hid out at Hagrid's, and;
3. When Professor Lupin confiscated the map.

I think these events were all close enough together such that it is not unreasonable to think that Harry may not have looked up his dot when he was with Ron and Scabbers in Gryffindor Tower.

Lupin probably did not use the map after he confiscated it, until the time in the book when he suspected Harry Ron and Hermione would attempt to visit Hagrid.

So I think it is believable that Peter went unnoticed until Lupin used the map to track Harry, and saw Peter on the map at Hagrid's.

Comment: Good point about scabbers hiding. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 8):

### Peter was not shown because the map knows the viewer's intention and only shows things of significance.

Although JKR has answered the question, perhaps we can postulate something else based on the books, as seemingly we clearly see that at least one time Scabbers did not always appear on the map:

> “Ron, I don’t believe it — it’s Scabbers!”
>    Ron gaped at her.
>    “What are you talking about?”
>    **Hermione carried the milk jug over to the table and turned it upside down**. With a frantic squeak,
>   and much scrambling to get back inside, Scabbers the rat came sliding out onto the table.
>    “Scabbers!” said Ron blankly. “Scabbers, what are you doing here?”

And then here:

> “The number of times I saw James disappearing under it…” said Lupin, waving an impatient
>   hand again. “The point is, even if you’re wearing an Invisibility Cloak, you still show up on the
>   Marauder’s Map. I watched you cross the grounds and enter Hagrid’s hut. Twenty minutes later,
>   you left Hagrid, and set off back toward the castle. **But you were now accompanied by somebody else**.”

Now, if Scabbers was hiding in Hagrid's hut, he should have always been visible! So why did Lupin not see him in Hagrid's hut the whole time? There's simply no way to answer there were too many dots, clearly, the only dots in Hagrid's hut at the time were Hagrid's and Pettigrew's!

We also see that the viewer isn't normally on the map:

> What did he have to do? He pulled out the map again and saw to his astonishment, that a new ink
>   figure had appeared upon it, **labeled ‘Harry Potter’**.

This clearly implies that Harry himself had not been on the map before! (If he was, the book should have said "he watched in astonishment as his dot grew bigger". Not the best proof, but supportive.)

However there are three facts about the map that can answer the question:
One, the map was invented for a specific purpose: Mischief:

> Messrs. Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot, and Prongs
>   **Purveyors of Aids to Magical Mischief-Makers** are proud to present
>    THE MARAUDER’S MAP.

Also:

> He took out his wand, touched the parchment lightly, and said, “**I solemnly swear that I am up to
>   no good**.”

Also

> “I’m getting there, Sirius, I’m getting there… well, highly exciting possibilities were open to us
>   now that we could all transform. Soon we were leaving the Shrieking Shack and roaming the
>   school grounds and the village by night. Sirius and James transformed into such large animals,
>   they were able to keep a werewolf in check. I doubt whether any Hogwarts students ever found
>   out more about the Hogwarts grounds and Hogsmeade than we did… **And that’s how we came to
>   write the Marauder’s Map**, and sign it with our nicknames. Sirius is Padfoot. Peter is Wormtail.
>   James was Prongs.”

These quotes show us that the map was intended for mischief, and specifically, was invented for James and Co. to be able to sneak around camp grounds.

The second fact that can answer this question is that the map is intelligent.

> But even as he stood there, flooded with excitement, something Harry had once heard Mr.
>   Weasley say came floating out of his memory.
>    **Never trust anything that can think for itself**, if you can’t see where it keeps its brain.
>    **This map was one of those dangerous magical objects** Mr. Weasley had been warning against…
>   Aids for Magical Mischief Makers…

And by the episode of Snape we see further evidence of the map's intelligence:

> “Professor Severus Snape, master of this school, commands you to yield the information you
>   conceal!” Snape said, hitting the map with his wand.
>    As though an invisible hand were writing upon it, words appeared on the smooth surface of the 
>   map.
>    “Mooney presents his compliments to Professor Snape, and begs him to keep his abnormally
>   large nose out of other people’s business.”

The third fact is that the map can change its appearance to help with the mischief:

> What did he have to do? He pulled out the map again and saw to his astonishment, that a new ink
>   figure had appeared upon it, labeled ‘Harry Potter’. This figure was standing exactly where the
>   real Harry was standing, about halfway down the third-floor corridor. Harry watched carefully.
>   **His little Ink self appeared to be tapping the witch with his minute wand. Harry quickly took out
>   his real wand and tapped the statue. Nothing happened. He looked back at the map. The tiniest
>   speech bubble had appeared next to his figure. The word inside said, ‘Dissendium.’**

This is incredible! The map not only deviated from its purpose (showing Hogwarts) it realized that Harry did not understand how to open the secret passage, so first it showed him the wand-tap, but Harry still didn't get it, so the second time Harry looked, it showed him the spell! **So this map can realize the viewer's intention and difficulties**!

So we know 4 facts from the books: 
1)Not every dot appears on the map.
2)The map is intended for mischief.
3)The map is intelligent.
4)Using its intelligence, the map can change its appearance to help with the mischief.

From these four facts **we can deduce that the map does not show everybody at once, but rather shows only people who the viewer is specifically looking for 
or that the map feels can interfere with the viewer's intended mischief** (or the whatever the viewers intention is) with the map.

This is further proven by the dots shown to Harry the first time he uses it:

> A labeled dot in the top left corner showed that Professor
>   Dumbledore was pacing his study; the caretaker’s cat, Mrs. Norris, was prowling the second
>   floor; and Peeves the Poltergeist was currently bouncing around the trophy room.

And also (GOF):

> Out in the dark corridor, Harry examined the Marauder’s Map
>   to check that the coast was still clear. Yes, the dots belonging to
>   Filch and his cat, Mrs. Norris, were safely in their office . . . nothing
>   else seemed to be moving apart from Peeves, though he was
>   bouncing around the trophy room on the floor above.

In all those cases, the dots shown to Harry were those that would cause an impediment to Harry's purpose (sneaking around).

**Therefore, we can answer all the questions "Why didn't x appear on the Mauraders Map" with a simple answer: It didn't affect whatever they were using the map for at the time. Thus there was no need to show them.**

This explains why Lupin didn't see Peter until after he joined with Harry and Ron: because Lupin was keeping an eye out only for Harry, Peter was of no significance and thus the map didn't show him, but after he joined with Harry, it became significant for Lupin's use of the map, and thus the map showed him.

This also explains why nobody saw Moody in Crouch's trunk and Sirius or Rita Skeeter in Animagus form: Because they were insignificant for the map's purpose.

This also why Harry didn't notice impostor Moody as Crouch until he tried looking in Snape's office: Since Snape's office was significant for Harry, the map showed Crouch.

This is further proven by this statement of Fred:

> “Right,” said George briskly. “Don’t forget to wipe it after you’ve used it —”
>    **“— or anyone can read it,” Fred said warningly**.
>    “Just tap it again and say, ‘Mischief managed!’ And it’ll go blank.”

Now, if there are hundreds of dots on the map, who cares if anyone can read it!?
But if the map only shows what is necessary for the viewer, if an authority figure would use it, the map becomes quite dangerous indeed.

Comment: How can you ignore an author's answer? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Edlothiad Same way I ignore her when she says Cursed Child is canon: Because not everything JKR says is canon. If her books imply one thing and she says another, I go with the books.

Comment: While is an astoundingly well research theory, in the end that is all it is....

Comment: We can not ignore canon established by the author where it suits us just because it does not fit our own headcanon.

Comment: @Skooba Its not just well researched - the book itself clearly says that Scabber was not always visible, regardless of what JKR says.

Comment: @skooba neither can the author. JKR's interviews are not canon if they are contradicted by the books.

Comment: This is your interpretation of HP canon. As there is no official canon, you are able to determine it how you want to determine it, this site often uses Author canon as the highest level, that means if she retcons something, that's canon

Comment: @Edlothiad "this site often uses Author canon as the highest level"
SO DO I! Thats why if the book says something clearly, I wont pretend its not there because a few years later the author changed her mind.

Comment: @TheAsh Yes, she can, that is her right as the author. In this case I don't see how it contradicts the books anyway. It contradicts your theory, which yes you have found circumstantial evidence, but you are using it to make it fit your theory.

Comment: @Skooba she clearly writes that Lupin did not see Pettigrew until they left Hagrid's hut!

Comment: @Skooba do you believe CC is cannon?

Comment: @TheAsh Absolutely, I may not like it, but that is how the story is presented.  The Creators are just that, they create the canon. Not many people like The Phantom Menace either, but it is canon to the Star Wars universe.

Comment: You may find [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117948/which-harry-potter-works-are-considered-canon) and [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10015/should-cursed-child-answers-be-given-to-harry-potter-questions) on how we treat different canon levels for Harry Potter.

Comment: @skooba I prefer this answer, particular the last part: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117958/89771

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is well argued, but I disagree with the conclusion. I don't think the map cared much about Harry's intentions. Sneaking into forbidden places is one of the main goals of the Map, and the seven secret corridors (one of which lead to Hogsmeade) are surely very important information that the Map is supposed to relay.  Hard-coding a message about how to open the secret passages seems like a completely reasonable thing to add to a good Map.

Comment: @Skooba - The top answer to that first link says that CC isn't canon.

Comment: @ibid The way I read it, it says that it is, just lower on the totem pole. Also consider the meta post. This site accepts CC as canon.

Comment: @Skooba - The answer gives a complete spectrum, including things line the movies and fanfiction as well. CC appears as either the lowest canon work it the highest non-canon work, depending on how you want to look at it.

Comment: There's no evidence for your assertions that a) people viewing the map aren't shown on it (the included quote in fact indicates the opposite); b) Lupin should have seen Wormtail in Hagrid's hut (he says himself that he wasn't looking at the map before that evening); c) the map only shows potential trouble-makers (the later books actually describe the hundreds of dots which are moving around; Harry can't locate Malfoy among the masses); d) the Map wouldn't be of any use to anyone if found unwiped (even with hundreds of dots, it's a unique, potentially dangerous and intelligent artifact).

Comment: @TheDarkLord a)Actually, if Harry was originally shown on the map, the map should have said "He saw his dot get larger" or something similar, therefore it implies a viewer isn't shown on the map until necessary b)Why didn't Lupin see Wormtail when Ron and Hermione were in the hut THAT EVENING c)good point. I'll need to think about that. d)yes, dangerous, but not so that it would concern Fred and George, my point was based on Fred and George being concerned about wiping as opposed to the existence of the wiping mechanism itself.

Comment: I really appreciate the work you've put into this, but I think you're reading *way* too much into Hagrid's hut. It really sounds to me like they went into Hagrid's Hut and disappeared from the map and then reappeared when they left the Hut "I watched you cross the grounds and enter Hagrid’s hut. Twenty minutes later, you left Hagrid, and set off back toward the castle. But you were now accompanied by somebody else." Even by your own theory, why would the map suddenly kick in and show Peter only when they left the Hut? The Map is a map of Hogwarts and its grounds after all. So it shows the hut

Comment: But why would you expect it to show the interior of the hut or its occupants, it isn't a map of Hagrid's private residence, but of the school. And would the Marauders ever have gone in there to map it out anyway? In fact, Peter who wrote the Map would have known if the interior of Hagrid's hut didn't appear on the Map and that would give him all the more reason to go and hide there rather than, say, the kitchens

Comment: Also note that what appears on the Map is "a new ink figure" and not a labelled dot like normal. To me this suggests not necessarily that Harry wasn't on the Map before and now he had appeared, but instead that the map is now showing him how to use the passageway by means of a figure, which is new. So I definitely agree the Map can show you stuff and get your intentions, I don't think there's anything to suggest it shows or hides people so you can find who you want, that's contradicted by other info such as him having to look for people, and him thinking he missed malfoy in the sea of dots

Comment: I think it's a stretch to say intent matters here. The map told him the password because that was designed into the map. After all it had a thorough overview of the castle. I'm pretty sure too that this is explained in the book though I might be remembering that wrong or it was inferred.

Answer (score 6):

Edited to correct my faulty memory,

In the film Harry did see Peter Pettigrew.  When Harry was walking down one of the corridors at night he saw Peter coming towards him on the map but he couldn't see anybody because Peter was in his Scabbers form.
Later when Lupin confiscated the map, Harry told him that it didn't work right because it showed Peter Pettigrew who was supposedly dead.

In the book Harry never uses the map when Ron has Scabbers with him.  As to why Fred and George never saw him it may be explained with how the map is built.

[This video of the Noble Collection Marauders Map](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3SapHaubc) shows separate sections of the map that allow you to essentially zoom in on a specific area.  You start with a large view of all of Hogwarts and then fold out other parts of the map depending on need.  As Fred and George were more intent on either getting out of Hogwarts or hiding from certain people they may not have bothered with looking for where Percy was.

As to the question of the number of people at Hogwarts which keeps popping up as a reason why they never saw him:

[BeyondHogwarts](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/doing-the-math-how-many-kids-are-at-hogwarts.html) lists JK Rowling saying there are around 1,000 students.

[HarryPotterLexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/essays/essay-hogwarts-how-many.html) says the books show about 300 with 5 boys and 5 girls added to each house every year.

[Another HPLexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/jkr-letter-responses.html) comment has Rowling saying 600 but admitting she is bad at math.

Comment: And how the map was revealed to Severus and Remus was also different in the book. In the book iirc Hermione had to go to the witch statue to get Harry's cloak back as it was too risky now that Harry had been discovered to be interested in that place - by Severus no less.

Answer (score 3):

Hogwarts has hundreds people in it IIRC. People looking at the map would only pay attention to locations/names that were interesting for their purposes or violated expected patterns. NOBODY would be checking the location of the Gryffindor's dormitories where Scabbers was most of the time.

Comment: All of Britain had 3k, Hogwarts had 1000, according to JKR; and possibly fewer based on later comments and evidence from the book.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that to see someone on the Marauder's Map the viewer has to know them rather personally (otherwise the map would be loaded with extraneous information)

All of the people who appear on the map have to be a subject of great focus in the viewer's mind (such as people securing the hallways).

Harry never looked at the map for "dad's old friends" or anything of that sort.  Lupin was able to see Pettigrew because he knew Pettigrew well and had probably looked for him on the map before.

Comment: Nope. The map showed everyone present at Hogwarts, and didn't take into account the viewer's preferences or interests.

Comment: In the books I've only seen reference to it being capable of revealing everyone present, not that they are all constantly shown.

In the movies the map clearly only shows people relevant to the person viewing the map.

Considering Hogwarts' numerous floors, rooms and passages it is infeasible that the map displays all of the thousands of dots.  If the magic were to be fueled by intent then extraneous information should easily be filtered.

Comment: And the map takes into account the person reading it as evident when Snape attempts to read the map.

Comment: When Snape attempted to read the map, it had been turned off (with "mischief managed").

Comment: So why did Harry saw the name of Peter Pettigrew on the marauder map while lurking in the school?
He wasn't thinking about his father friend, he was only scared of filch or rogue...

Comment: @max pnj Do you mean Snape ?

Comment: @pwassonne I believe Snape is Rogue in the French translation.

Comment: @Mac Cooper Yes, precisely. I was pointing it out because not everyone knows or will look it up. :)

Comment: @pwassonne d'oh! I thought you were asking :D

Comment: I was being polite, or trying to ^-^ sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @maxpnj (According to some of the other answers/comments) Harry didn't ever see Peter on the map (in the books).

Comment: @Pwassonne and Mac Cooper, yes, excuse my french...
I was speaking about snape by forgot to translate his name...

Answer (score 2):

There's no way that Scabbers lived with the Weasley family for 12 years and the twins never noticed him sleeping with Ron every night.

I prefer to think that the twins just assumed the map didn't work on animals. Or maybe they thought that scabbers's original name had been Peter and didn't think anything of it. It wouldn't be too strange in the wizarding world for rats to have first and last names.

Maybe they noticed and just didn't care. After all, the name didn't mean anything to them.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious?

Nobody knew who Peter Pettigrew was. Just like Harry didn't know who Sirius Black was at first. They didn't teach them about Sirius Black and Peter Pettigrew. People only knew about Sirius because of his escape. So none of the students know who Pettigrew was. And Harry did see him. Remember he went and told Lupin about it?

Comment: So... why is this "Peter" in Ron's bed every night?

Comment: Ron told Harry about the largest bit of Pettigrew found and sent back to his mum being his finger—so ye, not only did people know who Pettigrew was, they were fairly intimately familiar with the story.

Comment: Everyone thought Peter was dead. The twins would have assumed he was a homonym, or a distant relation who happened to share his common given name.

Comment: As for why he was in bed with Ron, either the twins didn't look at Ron's dormitory, or they noticed and were discreet enough for once not to mention it to Ron or Harry because some things are not joking matters. Most likely they didn't look, because I would have been worried if my older brother's ex boyfriend was sleeping with my 11-12yo younger brother.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to tell exactly where someone is. You might see Peter in the Gryffindor common room, but not that he is specifically in Ron's bed because that's just a tiny area of the castle. Also, whenever Ron was sleeping in the dorm with Scabbers up to four other people would be sleeping as well. So the dots would just be on top of each other and a mess.

To be honest, at night the Gryffindor common room would probably be just a big black blob of names and dots on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this is a good question,  and I have a theory.

### Lupin was able to see Peter Pettigrew on the Marauders' map because he was the only possessor who knew that Peter was an Animagus

Fred, George, Harry, and Snape at first did not know that Peter Pettigrew was an Animagus, but professor Lupin, his once-friend, knew it, and hence was able to see him as Peter Pettigrew on the map, and not as Scabbers.

Even if they were able to see the rat as Peter Pettigrew on the map, it wouldn't have made so much of a change to the story. And also, unlike in the book, in the movie, Harry is able to see Peter on the map, which quite of seems disastrous for this theory.

Comment: This is actually a great headcanon. If you would have evidence it would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a combination of perception, awareness, and focus. Even if the map shows the position/direction of anyone in a given area, maybe you have to know or be looking for a certain person for their name to show up?

Honestly, if you were trying to find one particular person on the map and he was in a crowd, everyone's names would be literally on top of each other. Thus making the names unreadable. That would make no sense. So maybe you have to be focusing on that specific person or "dot" to see the name?

Answer (score -2):

Lupin was one of the original creators of the Marauder's Map so he knew more about it than Harry, the twins or anyone except Peter and Sirius.

Comment: Yes but Fred, George and Harry were all perfectly proficient in using the Map. They never have any problems in using it or in locating people on it so it can't be that Lupin was so much better at using the Map. Unless you have some evidence to back up your point?